# windows shortcut key with out ctrl-alt

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I was using AutoHotKey, and its a powerful tool, but it seems to sometimes send false keys (aka ones I'm not pressing during a game). So I decided to simply stop using it because the only thing I was using in my ahk script was the keyboard short cut win-z to start the screen saver.

So I got a .bat file to run the screen saver. But when I was setting the keyboard shortcut in the shortcut I made for it, I couldn't use win-z anymore, it had to be ctrl-alt-z.

so I'm wondering if I can have a shortcut that uses a letter, but not ctrl-alt, (preferable the windows key). If this isn't possible, then I'll just have to use ctrl-alt-z.

Comment: You have an AutoHotkey script with a single shortcut for win-z and "it seems to sometimes send false keys"?  Did you check the script keyhistory when this happened?  Does your script capture/send keystrokes for other things?  If so you could probably strip those out and use only the single shortcut.

Comment: the ahk scrip sending the wrong keys happened so rarely that it would be impossible to test, and the file I was using was pretty long, so it might have been that, but that isn't the question.

Comment: Use ahk to recognize win-z and run your batch file

Comment: I don't really want to use ahk, personally I think ahk is very powerful, but I was having some odd button presses happening, so now I want to use something else, preferably the built in windows hot key function.